# PHP Soap api сформировать запрос\ответ?

Tags: php, api, php7, soap

Пытаюсь разобраться с SOAP api.
У меня есть эндпоинт, запрос я создаю используя метод __doRequest(), полный запрос выглядит так -

```
$url = 'http://.../onlinestore_ws.asmx?WSDL';
$action = 'http://tempurl.org/f_get_items_list'

$xmlrequest = '<x:Envelope
xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:tem="http://tempurl.org">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <tem:f_get_items_list>
        <tem:str1>
            <tem:str_items_list>
                <tem:item_code>?</tem:item_code>
                <tem:item_international_barcode>?</tem:item_international_barcode>
                <tem:item_total_balance_qty>0</tem:item_total_balance_qty>
                <tem:item_enduser_sellprice>0</tem:item_enduser_sellprice>
                <tem:item_unit_cost>0</tem:item_unit_cost>
                <tem:item_card_lastupdate>2020-09-18T00:00:00</tem:item_card_lastupdate>
            </tem:str_items_list>
        </tem:str1>
    </tem:f_get_items_list>
</x:Body>
</x:Envelope>';

$client = new SoapClient($url);

$test = $client->__doRequest($xmlrequest, $url, $action, 1.2, 0);
```

Проблема в том, что ответ мне приходит, в виде строки, НО не в виде XML разметки с данными, а чисто сами данные, тоесть голые цифры, которые никак распарсить в принципе нельзя, потому как , сегменты (если можно так выразится) разной длинны, и не разделены ничем
Пример
string(1854900) "01010-1.000001.451.45002020-02-15T20:41:35.5161001000209.00190.07992020-02-18T13:22:36.37310000100000570.00285.00002015-10-20T15:07:41.00310001100010600.00300.00002015-10-20T15:07:41.3610002100020540.00270.00002015-10-20T15:07:41.7210003100030600.00300.00002015-10-20T15:08:00.14310004100040640.00320.00002015-10-20T15:08:00.5

Может я как то не так отсылаю запрос ? Мне бы получить данные с XML разметкой или сразу в объекте.

PS эндпоинт я тестировал через boomerangapi., экстеншн хрома,
всё в порядке, ответ приходит такой какой нужно, но через PHP код получаю голые цифры !

**UPD:**
Модет кому то поможет -

$test2 = $client-> __getFunctions(); - обратился что-бы узнать все функции, но я и так и знал (не знак как готовить)

Дальше по структуре XML запроса, составил массив :

```
$serviceArguments = array ("str1"=>
array('str_items_list'=>
array('item_code' => '?',
        'item_total_balance_qty' => 0,
        'item_enduser_sellprice' => 0,
        'item_unit_cost' => 0,
        'item_card_lastupdate' => '2020-09-21T00:00:00')));
```

Дальше обратился к методу и закинул аргументы в виде массива, вот так :

```
$test2 = $client->__call('f_get_items_list',array('str1' => $serviceArguments));
```

В итоге получил объект, который не сложно было распарсить
Благодарю !

Comment: Попробуйте использовать генератор [PHP классов из WSDL](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator) и с ним сделать запросы.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать вызов процедуры так: `<?php  $resp = $client->f_get_items_list((object)['paramA' => "A", 'paramB" => "B", ...]); print_r($resp); ?>`

Comment: Да, благодарю, я так как раз и сделал в итоге !